# Facebook Login Button Closing Login Activity

Tags: android, facebook

The Facebook login button in my splash activity is closing splash activity without going to the next activity. By the looks of the logcat, the onSuccess method is not even being called. Anyway to get it to go to next activity?

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private Intent intent;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mNextRunnable;
    private final long SPLASH_TIME = 3000;
    private VideoView videoHolder;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ImageView iv;
    private static final String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

//        try {
//            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
//                    "info.nexrave.nexrave",
//                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
//            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
//                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
//                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
//                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
//            }
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//
//        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Video about to be called");
        //Video settings
        videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.video_footage);
        videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
        videoHolder.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
        videoHolder.start();

        //Facebook settings
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_splash_logo);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        // Callback registration
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: registering callback");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallBack);
//        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken About To Be Called");
//        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
//            @Override
//            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
//                updateWithToken(newAccessToken);
//            }
//        };
        updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    private void makeVisible() {
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv.bringToFront();
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginButton.bringToFront();
    }

    private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called");
        if (currentAccessToken != null) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: User logged in");
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, FeedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME);

        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: Not logged in");
                    makeVisible();
                    Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: finished");
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME);
        }
    }

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: Done");
            //Placeholder: Need to check firebase to see if already registered
            intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, EnterPhoneNumber.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.d(TAG, "UpdateWithToken Called: error");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: provide your logcat output ...unless it is hard to debug

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Logcat output is showing every log I have there, except for the one's in the FacebookCallback

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things i noticed...

Declare

```
Profile profile;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
```

In your onCreate()

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            updateWithToken(newToken);
        }
    };
    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

   loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
```

in your updateWithToken() method

```
private void updateWithToken(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

    if (currentAccessToken != null) {
        //User logged In--do your stuff
    } else {
        //user not logged in
    }
}
```

Also in your callback method

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        try {
            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                        // profile2 is the new profile
                        profile = profile_new;
                        Log.v("facebook - profile", profile_new.getFirstName());
                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                    }
                };
                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
            } else {
                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                Log.v("facebook - profile", profile.getFirstName());
            }

            Intent  intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EnterPhoneNumber.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERRROR", e.toString());
    }
};
```

Also check Key Hash is added properly in developer panel

Add this on manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/APP_ID" />
```

Also in your layout:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_left_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_right_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_facebook"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Login with Facebook"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Even when I start tracking, accesstoken is still null. The oncallback methods are never called

Comment: Hash key is properly added, I copied it straight from android monitor/logcat.

Comment: @Shane see edited answer and if that not works...try uninstall the app and reinstall it again..i find that the access token that was returned by the LoginManager will be saved in shared preferences